# 3D from 2D picture options

Tags: 3d-design

If I want to make 3D printable objects out of my old drawings, what are my options? Do I need to redraw the entire thing in 3D or is there a better way?

This is an example of the sort of pictures I have, I long ago lost the original Macromedia files so I just have them like this.

[image: example pic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume that what you are saying is that you only have a rasterized image file. For example a .PNG file, and that you don't have any kind of source file containing vectors.

Since you're already a skilled artist from the looks of it, you're largely limited by the software that you have access to, or how much you're willing to spend on new software.

Probably the simplest and cheapest way would be to use a free program such as Inkscape to redraw your image as lineart only (You can import the image into the software and then trace over it). Draw it completely flat and 2 dimensional with no shading or colors. Only lines to represent edges. Save it as a Structured Vector Image (The default file for Inkskape). Then import it into a free 3D package such as blender.

This will import your image as a series of 2D lines in a 3D space. You can then use traditional 3D art skills (Which you may or may not have yet) to give it 3 dimensions.

A complex shape like that might require a resin printer to print due to the high level of detail. Making it wouldn't be a task for the faint of heart.

A more expensive option would be to commission a professional to do it for you.

Comment: Yeah I've spent hours trying to find a shortcut, but I think you're right... start again from scratch

Comment: As an aside, consider if your objective is to extrude in a single direction, Blender is going to be far more complex than needed. Even Tinkercad will allow extrusion of SVG files. I'd also expect 3DBuilder (win10) to have that feature but I'm currently unable to verify.

Comment: Any 3D modelling package that can deal with an SVG file from an art package would do. They could even skip the SVG import and trace their image directly in the 3D software using curves. But that might be a little unintuitive when it comes to complicated details.

Comment: @fred_dot_u The issue isn't extruding an svg, I can do that a number of ways. It's the easiest way of getting an svg. I drew these 16 years ago when I had plenty of time and quiet (before I had 6 kids). On the bright side 3dbuilder will allow me to get an silhouette, messes up all the internal stuff but better than nothing

Comment: @Kilisi, I and a friend are teaching ourselves to learn Rhino3D using online resources. It's similar to blender, but perhaps not as complex, but also not a free program. Both of those programs would allow you to manually manipulate the elevation of the appropriate areas. If this was a real world carving, for example, you'd be able to perform photogrammetry to get a mesh, but a bunch of ifs do not create a solution.